# Updating UITableViewCell not refreshing the UI

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4, uitableview

I have a UITableView and on the first time cellForRowAtIndexPath is called, I save all the UITableViewCell values I return.  I do this so that I can update the contents when ever  the underlying data changes.

However, when I update the contents of the UITableViewCell, the UITableView does not show the new entries until I scroll up and down on the UI.  How do I programatically force the refresh?

Answer (score 1):

The UITableView has a method „reloadData.“ Just call it:

```
[tbl reloadData]
```

Comment: Yes but perhaps he wants to keep his eye on the selected cell. no ?

Comment: And I do call reloadData but that does not seem to cause the UITableView to update its contents...

Answer (score 1):

You can first save the index position of your cell, refresh your datas and then scroll automatically to your index.

So save it then call reloadData method and then scroll it to your save.